# visual studio code editor not recognizing opencv path in c++ include headers

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-code

I am usig visual studio code editor on windows 7 to compile c++ project however I see error in editor that include file not found in browser.path.

Below is the include:

```
 #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

Below is the c_cpp_properties.json file.

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceRoot}",
            "/usr/include",
            "/usr/local/include"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Linux",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceRoot}",
            "/usr/include",
            "/usr/local/include"
        ],
        "defines": [],
        "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceRoot}",
            "A:/Program Files/VC/include/*",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/um",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/shared",
            "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/winrt",
            "A:/OPENCV-32/opencv/build/include"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE"
        ],
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "A:/Program Files/VC/include/*",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/um",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/shared",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/winrt"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
         }
      }
   ]
 }
```

Comment: just `"A:/OPENCV-32/opencv/build/include"`

Comment: @Miki corrected by confiig still same, I have updated my full config in the edit